# left/right floated divs acting funny with centered img

Tags: css, html

Here's the code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PtVVD/).

Not sure what is causing the right arrow button to jump down. If I remove the image, it is up where it's supposed to be. Where's the error?

Comment: please make your question self-contained (include relevant code snippets, demonstrate the issue etc.), so others may benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the right floated element before the left and center item. Float right first, then float left.

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PtVVD/1/)

Comment: Is this an actual rule, or just good practice?

Comment: It's very good practice for most browsers.

Comment: @Jon--its also an actual rule for many browsers.

Answer (score 2):

just replace the order of the image and the right arrow like in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/PtVVD/5/